# collectList() returns an empty list and does not enter the defaultIfEmpty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have the following code:

```
@GetMapping("/enrollment/{id}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> findByEnrollment(@PathVariable("id") String enrollment){
    return Mono.just(enrollment)
               .flatMap(e -> technomechanicalService.findByEnrollmentVehicle(e)
                                                    .collectList()
                                                    .map(t -> ResponseEntity.ok()
                                                                            .body(new Response(t, HttpStatus.OK.value(), null)))
                                                    .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), "No se encontro la placa!"), 
                                                                            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)));

}
```

when consuming from a client (postman) with a value that does not exist in mongodb it does not go to the defaultIfEmpty.

The solution I gave you is to add a filter before the map. As seen below:

```
@GetMapping("/enrollment/{id}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> findByEnrollment(@PathVariable("id") String enrollment){
    return Mono.just(enrollment)
               .flatMap(e -> technomechanicalService.findByEnrollmentVehicle(e)
                                                    .collectList()
                                                    .filter(t -> {
                                                        if(!t.isEmpty()) return true;
                                                        return false;
                                                    })
                                                    .map(t -> ResponseEntity.ok()
                                                                            .body(new Response(t, HttpStatus.OK.value(), null)))
                                                    .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), null), 
                                                                            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)));

}
```

My question is where would the .defaultIfEmpty () go?

Comment: `it does not go to the defaultIfEmpty` please update with where does it go?

Answer (score 1):

`defaultIfEmpty()` not work after `.collectList()` because `.collectList()` returning Mono with empty list its not equals empty, so `defaultIfEmpty()` not work.

You can change ur method order but your map method ll work after `defaultIfEmpty()` method

Comment: Ok I understand that the `defaultIfEmpty()` cannot work after the `.collectList()` because it returns a mono with an empty list.

But then where would I go?

Comment: you can in a flatMap check if the list is empty and return a mono#empty from there, or execute something else.

Comment: in the present case you could test the list in the `map` directly (`t.isEmpty()`), which makes for a bit more complex lambda, but avoids the overhead of `flatMap` entirely